# How to automatically generate random numbers every second when the button is pressed only once in android?

Tags: android

I want to automatically generate random numbers every second when the button is pressed only once in android

Comment: you want to use this number once or every time ?

Comment: Call Random Method with Thread

Comment: every time.....

Answer (score 1):

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Random random = new Random();
        final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int randomNumber = random.nextInt();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task.run();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a runnable and a handler to activate that runnable every second, once the button is clicked.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            randomNumber();
        }
    }
```

then create the handler for that runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

inside your onClickListener for the button trigger the runnable by calling the following:

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

**EDIT:**
your random number generator could be something like this:

```
public int randomNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

it gives you a random number between 0-100